# What is this compression algorithm?

Tags: c#, compression, reverse-engineering

This is a decompression algorithm that I have decoded by reverse engineering.

But I am not good at studying compression algorithms, so I don't know the name of the compression algorithm or how to compress it.

The `tbl` is a array of signed 32-bit integers and of size 256. It is hardcoded in the executable. The array contains location offsets.

[Here](https://pastebin.com/krCcUKJZ) is a dump of the array (big-endian, text-based hex dump) and [here](https://pastebin.com/amGVeFJN) it's in a C++ format.

---

1. If possible, can you tell me how to compress method?
2. How can I know to compression method again with only the decompressing method? Or how should I study?

---

```cs
int srcCnt = 0;
int destCnt = 0;
decomIMP[destCnt++] = imp[srcCnt++]; 
while(true)
{
    try
    { 
       byte val = imp[srcCnt++];

       if (val == 0x10)
       {
           int count = imp[srcCnt++] + 3;
           byte value = decomIMP[destCnt - 1];
           for(int j = 0; j<count; j++)
           {
                decomIMP[destCnt++] = value;
           }
       }
       else if(val >= 0x80)
       {
           int val1 = imp[srcCnt++];
           int val2 = (val >> 4) & 0x7;
           int val3 = (val & 0x0f) + 3;
           int val4 = (int)TBL[val1] + destCnt;
           for (int j = 0; j < val3; j++)
           {
              byte value = decomIMP[val4++];
              decomIMP[destCnt++] = value;
           }
           for(int k =0; k < val2; k++)
           {
              byte value = imp[srcCnt++];
              decomIMP[destCnt++] = value;
           }
       }
       else if (val >= 0x20 && val < 0x80)
       {
           int val1 = val & 0xf;
           int val2 = (val >> 4) + 1;
           int val3 = (int)TBL[val1] + destCnt; 
           //infact, destCnt - tbl[val].. content of tbl is minus value

           for (int j = 0; j < val2; j++)
           {
              byte value = decomIMP[val3++];
              decomIMP[destCnt++] = value;
           }
       }
       else if (val < 0x10)
       {
           for(int j=0; j<=val; j++)
           {
                byte value = imp[srcCnt++];
                decomIMP[destCnt++] = value;
           }
       }
   }
   catch(IndexOutOfRangeException)
   {
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: some variable length encoding... are there no clues in the source?

Comment: when the header (`val`) is less that 0x10, it just does a single (lookup-indirect) read of the next `val+1` items (so a `val` of `0` reads `1` item)

when the header is 0x10, it looks to be run-length encoded - a count of the (lookup-indirect) next value, plus 3, of the *previously* decoded value

when the header is between (0x10, 0x20)... nothing happens?

when the header is between [0x20, 0x80) it ... repeats data from a previous block? otherwise it repeats some number of bytes from a previous block *and* then reads some other number of fresh bytes? not familiar with the algo but...

Comment: array of imp is just compressed data. i'm guess that conditions value(0x10,0x20) and tbl are added to the typical RLE compression algorithm.

Comment: yeah if data is between 0x10, 0x20.. don't decode data.. I've confirmed it for sure.

Comment: oh, yeah, my bad on misreading `imp` - but; your best bet is to get clues from the code... I mean, anyone who writes code like this without citing an algo is just... bad at leaving comments!

Comment: On brief inspection, it seems like like some variant of LZ.

Comment: Where do the contents of `TBL` come from? Is it some static array of offsets that's part of the reversed executable, or is this loaded from the compressed file? I guess is this from some fairly old game, eh.

Comment: tbl array is static array in arm9.bin exetuable.. Of course I know the general compression algorithms. But the problem is that this algorithm has additional conditions. That's the point.

Comment: Used to extract multiple compression background img files by using this tbl

Comment: Can you upload the the `TBL` array values somewhere (maybe pastebin, or even add it to the question)? | What I'm saying is that it's probably a custom implementation based on Lempel-Ziv. I see there are 4 different "codes" - literal, repeat last byte, length-distance (copy from decoded), and length-distance followed by literal. | To compress, I suppose you'd first detect repetitions, then look for matches in the sliding window and if both fail code a literal. A simple unoptimized compressor wouldn't be too difficult to implement (written similar thing maybe decade ago).

Comment: https://pastebin.com/krCcUKJZ  data type is uint32, infact, ``(int)TBL[val1] + destCnt; -> ex) destCnt + 0xFFFFFFFF == destCnt + (-1) ==  destCnt - 1`` if just in case you're confused..

Comment: [My current prototype](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2703fdcf90ccd249) -- sorry it's C++ (my C# is really rusty) but I tried to keep it simple. | There are some things missing (I don't support coding literals as part of the `code >= 0x80` chunks), and I have some ideas about coding few things more efficiently, but so far it seems reversible. | Could you provide couple of examples of compressed inputs, so I could verify my decoder matches your spec? Cheers.

Comment: thank you for your help...i got a hint as you said "Non-optimized code".               encoded file --  https://pastebin.com/iHQhmcGg                                                 decoded file -- https://pastebin.com/h42k5Q79  //bandai logo raw img(256*192,8bpp)

Comment: and for the correct code.. i modifyed  ``if (in_count >= in_size) { break; }`` --> try-catch. break automatically when array out of range

Comment: Thanks, those were useful. [New version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/54924b4de8a7cff9) - fixed minor bug in my decompressor. Added support for literals as part of `code >= 0x80` chunks. On your file it actually compresses better than the original (it seems their coding of repetitions has some inefficiencies) -- 2886 vs 2996 bytes (~3.5% better).